# Options for "Decorating" methods in Java Static Class without using AOJ or similar

Tags: java, reflection, proxy, annotations, invocationhandler

I have a static class that has a number of methods with different names but otherwise the same signature, e.g.:

```
protected static MyResponse [validationMethodName] (MyObject target, MyStatus failStatus) throws Exception {...}
```

I would like these particular methods to execute some code on entry, such as

```
target.checkCache(validationMethodName);
target.doOtherStuff();
```

without having to duplicate this code in each method.

I am looking into the following techniques and am wondering which if any might be possible/best, or if there's a better way:

- use a Proxy for the containing static class and add the desired code
  via the InvocationHandler
- extend the java.lang.reflect.method class with a special invoke()
- just duplicate the code in each method with some initial methodInit(args) call

I'm willing to use anything in core available through Java10

Comment: It's always static?

Comment: Yes.  Though I would be open to perhaps making the class non-static, depending on the benefit and clarity of the resulting code.

Comment: Your methods have different names?

Comment: yes, the methods have different names.  If it's not static, I imagine I can use a Proxy and annotations to make these particular methods execute additional code on the arguments.  But ideally, I wouldn't have to change this static class into a non-static class.

Comment: Maybe you can use Javassist? it will work without any special tool as long as this class is not loaded before editing it. Otherwise you could try to use java agents.
There is no other way to do this.